# Generating symfony type tutorials displaying code

Tags: html, symfony

I was wondering if anyone knew how the Symfony website generates the code to display code such as YAML, XML and PHP

eg: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html

Comment: What do you actually want? Display code on your website?

Comment: I have been looking for a good way to illustrate code on a website. I was wondering if there was some bundle they were using to create those tutorials with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the documentation on how the [Symfony2](http://symfony.com/) website does it:
[Symfony2 documentation: Format](http://symfony.com/doc/current/contributing/documentation/format.html)

Also there is this bundle (haven't tried it myself):
[nicodmf/HighlightBundle](https://github.com/nicodmf/HighlightBundle)

And you might want to take a look at:

- [GeSHi](http://qbnz.com/highlighter/)
- [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/)
- [Google Code Prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/)